# How to split string contains both double quotes and escape double quotes in JAVA?

Tags: java, string, split, double-quotes

Let's say I have one input string `"Tim \"Apple\"" "Mark \"FB\"" "Elon \"Cars\""`

I want to split that string into a String array based on the quotation block(not escape quotation block)
The result should look like:

```
[Tim "Apple", Mark "FB", Elon "cars"]
```

What should I do to get this result? Thanks a lot.

Comment: please show how that value can be `one` string

Comment: The input string you show actually contains 3 strings. Can you show how the program is going to get the input string(s)? also the result is not in valid Java syntax. Can you be more specific about what the result should look like?

Comment: I think the asker means that's one string read from some file, not that it appears that way in the Java source.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Re {
        public static List<String> parse(String s) {
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"([^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)+\"") // Match from one quote to the next non-escaped one
                        .matcher(s);
                List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
                while(m.find()) {
                        String match = m.group();
                        match = match.substring(1, match.length() - 1); // Remove the quotes from the beginning and end
                        match = match.replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1"); // Remove all escapes, without accidentally removing escaped backslashes
                        matches.add(match);
                }
                return matches;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(args[0]);
                System.out.println(parse(args[0]));
        }
}
```

Result:

```
"Tim \"Apple\"" "Mark \"FB\"" "Elon \"Cars\""
[Tim "Apple", Mark "FB", Elon "Cars"]
```